# Read csv into dataframe by ignoring "LF" and "CR LF" within field enclosure quotes (" ")

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a data file in which fields are enclosed within double quotes and field separator like below:

```
field enclosure = "<field_value>"
sep = ||@@##
```

So of the field values have text within quotes that have 'LF' and 'CR LF' line separators which are causing for the next lines to be printed on a new line - which may be misinterpreted as a new record, when in reality, it a part of one record, has the lines not been broken to shift to a new line.

example:

```
3||@@##14||@@##"2016-01-13 19:59:27"||@@##"2016-01-15 23:09:19"||@@##1162||@@##822||@@##1237||@@##\N||@@##"VHiujdfYshv"||@@##"---<LF>
...LF
"||@@##\N||@@##"2016-01-15 23:09:18"||@@##0||@@##1||@@##0||@@##0||@@##3||@@##1788||@@##\N||@@##205||@@##\N||@@##0||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##1||@@##\N||@@##"251 Bgegf BHVcvytd Street<CR LF>
JHbsdbfh, RF 35214<CR LF>
<CR LF>
xyz@gmail.dhg.com<CR LF>
<CR LF>
@@##1788<LF>
4||@@##14||@@##"2016-01-25 22:08:53"||@@##"2016-02-15 20:32:08"||@@##1097||@@##933||@@##1262||@@##\N||@@##"VHiujdfYshv"||@@##"--- <LF>
...<LF>
```

Please note that the `LF` and `CR LF` actually show up without the angle brackets, which is, probably, a given, but I am mentioning it for absolute clarity. Below is a snip of how that looks on a notepad++ file. Also, note that my data consists of '||@@##' as a field separator, with '\N' for the na_values.

Below is how I am reading this file so far. I tried to use 'quotechar' and 'quoting' params from the pd.read_csv, but that uses a C parser, which separator uses a Python parser, so python parser is overriding. How do I read this file <process it before reading as a CSV, or use some regex while reading a CSV file? Please help.

```
df =  pd.read_csv(z.open(filename), 
                              encoding = 'utf8',
                              header=None,
                              sep='\|\|@@##',
                              na_values='\\N',
                             engine = 'python')
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a regex? Remove linebreaks?

Comment: Yes, those line breaks, either CRLF or LF which are breaking my record, should show up only in one line and NOT* separate lines.

Comment: It looks like you have CRLF only inside the records and if you remove them, the records will be on one line. Then, try `with open(filepath, 'rb') as file: with open(savefilepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw: fw.write( file.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'').decode('utf-8') )`. Then you can read in the `savefilepath` file into a dataframe with pandas.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for your response! I will try this out for CRLF. I do have an LF inside the quotes, that is the field enclosure. Check out the first line in the image that I have shared. How do u suggest I remove the LF?

Comment: So, if you want to remove all single LFs and keep CRLFs, you need `with open(filepath, 'rb') as file: with open(savefilepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw: fw.write( re.sub(r'(?<!\r)\n', '', file.read()).decode('utf-8') )`

Comment: So, does it work?

Comment: Hey, it does not do exactly what I want. Apologies if I have not been clear before, 

I need to remove all the LF and CRLF which are bound within double quotes, there can be any text or characters following or preceding the LF and CRLF within double quotes, and I want to remove them so all the content within the quotes fits in a single line.

Also, is there a way to work with this without saving the files - without using the `savepathfile`. I am dealing with a large amount of data and saving the files is going to be expensive.

Comment: You do not have to save the files. However, since your matches span across multiple lines, you will have to read the whole file into memory. Basically, you need to use `with open(filepath, 'r') as file: content = re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace("\n", ""), file.read())`. If the files are messy, you might need ``with open(filepath, 'r', newline="\n") as file: content = re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: re.sub(r'[\u000A-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]', '', x.group()), file.read())``

Comment: What are all those characters in the re.sub - `\u000A-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000` 
what is the significance of using this ?

I am also getting an error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 39667: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Ok, [here is the demo](https://ideone.com/yMh3Sx).

Comment: I get it now, thank you for sharing the demo with me. It is producing exactly what I need. Thank you so much!! 

you can post this as a solution to my question and I can mark that as the right answer for my requirements. It may help others coming across something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
rx_lbr = r'[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+'
with open(filepath, 'r', newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as fr:
  with open(savefilepath, 'w', newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as fw:
    fw.write( re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: re.sub(rx_lbr, '', x.group()), fr.read()) )
```

The `"[^"]*"` regex with `re.sub` matches all non-overlapping substrings between single quotes, and the `lambda x: re.sub(rx_lbr, '', x.group())` replacement removes all vertical whitespace Unicode chars from the match only. So, all other line breaks remain unchanged.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yMh3Sx):

```py
import re
content = r"""3||@@##14||@@##"2016-01-13 19:59:27"||@@##"2016-01-15 23:09:19"||@@##1162||@@##822||@@##1237||@@##\N||@@##"VHiujdfYshv"||@@##"---
...
"||@@##\N||@@##"2016-01-15 23:09:18"||@@##0||@@##1||@@##0||@@##0||@@##3||@@##1788||@@##\N||@@##205||@@##\N||@@##0||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##\N||@@##1||@@##\N||@@##"251 Bgegf BHVcvytd Street
JHbsdbfh, RF 35214
 
xyz@gmail.dhg.com
 
@@##1788
4||@@##14||@@##"2016-01-25 22:08:53"||@@##"2016-02-15 20:32:08"||@@##1097||@@##933||@@##1262||@@##\N||@@##"VHiujdfYshv"||@@##"---
"""
print( re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: re.sub(r'[\r\n\x0B\x0C\u0085\u2028\u2029]+', '', x.group()), content) )
```